# Android studio multi var return value for url

Tags: android, url, android-studio, hyperlink

I want make url in android studio.
When I make multi var, I can see wrong word in emulate.
Below is source code.

`content[i]` has number and `title[i]` has text.

`"content[1] = 1 content[2] = 2 content[3] = 3..."`

`"title[1] = test1 title[2] = test2 title[3] = test3..."`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            dist[i] = new TextView(this);
            contentid[i] = new TextView(this);
            title[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

            NodeList distList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("dist");
            Element distElement = (Element) distList.item(0);
            distList = distElement.getChildNodes();

            NodeList contentidList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("contentid");
            Element contentidElement = (Element) contentidList.item(0);
            contentidList = contentidElement.getChildNodes();
            contentid[i].setText(((Node) contentidList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            NodeList titleList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
            Element titleElement = (Element) titleList.item(0);
            titleList = titleElement.getChildNodes();
            title[i].setText("TITLE = "
                    + ((Node) titleList.item(0)).getNodeValue() + ((Node) distList.item(0)).getNodeValue());


            title[i].setClickable(true);
            title[i].setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

            String URL_ANSWER = "<a href='http://korean.visitkorea.or.kr/kor/bz15/where/festival/festival.jsp?cid="+ contentid[i] + "'>" + title[i] + "</a>";
            title[i].setText(Html.fromHtml(URL_ANSWER));

            // addView is best used with setting LayoutParams.
            // eg addView(view, layoutParams). The following is for simplicity.

            layout.addView(title[i]);

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format your code sample so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including your TextView on the url, try like this:

```
String URL_ANSWER = "<a href=\"http://korean.visitkorea.or.kr/kor/bz15/where/festival/festival.jsp?cid="+ contentid[i] + "\">" +"</a>";
```

Comment: thx. That is not work. and I tried that before i write question.

Comment: Add a log after this line to see the final string.

Comment: that is not work. I think emulate show content[i] variable.

Comment: so I tried I think contentid[i] return and set another value. But I have no source